# Is there a C# library for SQLite that does not require the C++ runtimes?

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite

We have been moving our small application databases to SQLite at work and ran into an issue where one user who installed our program did not have the C++ runtimes. We are using System.Data.SQLite and the program would not work because of this, obviously.

My colleague has said that, for any library or system we implement, "if it requires C++ runtimes then use somehting else." It causes a lot of issues.

I know that SQLite is written in C++, but is there an implementation of any kind that is not? Is there an implementation that does not require the C++ runtimes in windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C#-SQLite is an independent reimplementation of the SQLite software library version 3.7.7.1. 
It has been ported into managed code, written in C#

http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/